# ошибки в java способные положить приложение

Tags: java, исключения

Для выполнения задачи , нужно отлавливать в логах веб-приложения все ошибки JAVA. Наличие иных error'ов допускается , но т.к они все пишутся в одну кучу, кто-нибудь точно может назвать все возможные ошибки в java, способные положить приложение?

Comment: аут оф мемори можно пропустить ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые не проверяемые (unchecked) исключения могут положить, т.к. при их предположительном возникновении приложение все-равно будет собрано без обязательного `try`/`catch`.

Исключения `Error` и `RuntimeException`, и все их наследники — не проверяемые.

[На этой странице показано](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html) дерево классов.

Там и знаменитый `NullPointerException`, и `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

Линиями выделил не проверяемые исключения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки Error и отнаследованные ловить не нужно, сигнализирует о ошибках самой JVM. Из текста автора можно сделать вывод, что такие ошибки можно пропустить.

Ошибки Exception предназначены для ветвления логики и явной обработки. Позволяют иметь больше выходов из метода, чем простой return. Обработка таких ошибок форсирована. Такие ошибки тоже пропускаются для задачи.

Вам нужно ловить RuntimeException и его наследников.